# NFC Reader based project with microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, nfc

I'm familiar with NFC technology on the Android side, since I've made several applications with it. I'd like to make a very simple microcontroller based hardware with NFC reader P2P involved for practice purpose.

Where is a good place to start for such project? What board and/or NFC reader is generally recommended for such case? For now, I don't plan to do anything fancy other than maybe just turn on some LED lights based on NFC reads. I am a software engineer, so I'm not too fond of Electrical Engineering but I do have some experience working with breadboards and programming simple micro controllers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure TI has some NFC dev kits (and probably other companies).

Comment: Start from google "nfc starter kit".

Answer (score 1):

Many chip manufacturer company (e.g. TI, ST, NXP, etc.) produce chips and evaluation board and even SDK for thier own products.I have have only experiences in using NXP NFC solutions .OM25180FDK from nxp is based on PN5180 full NFC forum PCD with rich example and 4 layer ahrdware abstracted SDK,
TI ans ST also offer some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a lot of projects use the [NXP PN532](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/nxp/data-sheets/PN532_C1.pdf).

It has I2C and SPI interfaces, and is well-supported with open-source libraries:

- [Arduino / `adafruit-pn532`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/adafruit-pn532/)
- [x86 / libnfc](https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc)
- [ESP32 / esphome](https://esphome.io/components/binary_sensor/pn532.html?highlight=pn532)

Inexpensive breakout boards are easy to find:

- [Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/364) (US$39.95 as of Oct 2023)
- [Top eBay search result for “pn532”](https://www.ebay.com/itm/404262128785) (US$6.60 shipped as of Oct 2023)
- [Top AliExpress US search result for “pn532”](https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256805787598774.html) (US$2.75 as of Oct 2023)

I don’t see much reason to use anything else unless you have more specific requirements.